# how Exclamation mark before a falsy value works in if condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I found this when I was watching a project tutorial.

```
let isGameOver = false;

if(!isGameOver){
console.log('game goes on.')
}
if(isGameOver){
console.log('game over')
}
```

Inside this block, it seems "!" didn't negate the return of isGameOver.
It is more working like ：
`if(isGameOver == false){...} //they are working functionally same. if(!isGameOver){....}`
so why it didn't nagate isGameOver to truthy value like

```
 if(isGameOver == true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working just as it should. First though, understand that using the [logical NOT operator (`!`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#:%7E:text=The%20logical%20NOT%20(%20!%20),true%20%3B%20otherwise%2C%20returns%20true%20.) doesn't change the value of the item it is placed in front of - - it creates a new value to be used just in that expression. In other words after using `!isGameOver` in one expression, the value of that variable remains unchanged for future expressions. If you wanted to change the value of the variable, you'd write: `isGameOver = !isGameOver;`.

Your variable is set to `false` initially and then you check it for `!` (not), which would mean `true`. Since `true` is always `true`, the first `consoloe.log()` will fire. Then, your second test tests against `false` (the variable value) and since `false` is never `true`, the second `console.log()` doesn't fire:

```js
let isGameOver = false;

// Check to see if the opposite of isGameOver (false) is true (which it is):
if(!isGameOver){
  console.log('game goes on.')
}

// Check to see if isGameOver is true (which it isn't):
if(isGameOver){
  console.log('game over')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I was confused with the variable name isGameOver.Since it was initially set to false.,maybe it is better to change it to isGameRunning? so the code would be: let isGameRuning  = false; if(!isGameRunning){//game goes on//}} if(isGameRunning){//game over//}

Comment: @shawnx You should call it whatever makes logical sense. There's nothing wrong with `isGameOver` or `isGameRunning` as either one's value will be informative. Don't forget to up vote all helpful answers and consider marking this one as "the" answer.

Answer (score 0):

! negates the value.

Therefore if "isGameOver" is **false**, then "!isGameOver" is "true", which is why it passes the true condition in the first if.